# How to logout user from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase database using firebaseUser authorisation. I successfully logout user from app, but when I logout user the app is crashed due to firebase database reference. I got logcat message showing that

```
This client does not have permission to perform this operation.
```

How can I logout user from firebase database?

Comment: Why are you trying to log out ? If you are doing so then you have to ask your users to login again then perform db operation. "This client does not have permission to perform this operation." - You are trying to access your database who are not authenticated or logged out

Comment: @TGMCians if user has multiple accounts then user need logout option. In my app i want logout option

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple gmail accounts are configured on your device and you want to try with different accounts ?

Comment: @TGMCians no if there is a login option there must be a logout option need to give to user

Comment: Yep. Once you are log out from the app then you have to re-ask to user to login then you can perform database operation

Comment: @TGMCians yes. If user logged out user need to login again

Comment: Yep. So once you are logged in then still you get this "This client does not have permission to perform this operation." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added ValueEventListener to firebase database reference, when i'm trying to logout the user ValueEventListener is still running in background that's why my app is crashing.

I removed ValueEventListener from firebase database reference and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

You don't logout from the "database" as such, but logout from Firebase with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`.

After that, the user can't access parts of the database that requires user credentials, and I guess it's the reason why your app crashed. So when you make database calls, you need to check if the user has correct credential.