# Does signOut() automatically call ref.off() in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After application login google cloud, if application calls `auth.signOut()`, will the connections created using `ref.on()` automatically disconnect? Does the application have to call `ref.off()` to disconnect even through application has called `auth.signOut()`?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Someone asked a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183677/how-to-logout-user-from-firebase-database but you didn't provide what platform or language you're using so this might or might not help. The link says that if you call signOut, it won't affect the database meaning if you have rules on your realtime database then it would crash (at least in the context of Android) because you're trying to access data that is only restricted to a logged in user.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth.signOut()` signs out an authenticated user from the application, therefore there won't any currently logged in user in the application.

`ref.off()` will remove a Realtime database listener usually used before leaving a page, to save memory.

Both are not related to each other.